# How to preload differents clips with AudioSystem?

Tags: java, javasound

I'm integrated audio in a Java application. The problem is that sometimes clip.open() hangs up a little so I've read that I need to reload the clip and then just clip.start().

I'm using a sound class for each audio file, it reloads the clip once it has finish playing.
The problem here is that the sound I trigger doesn't play right when I trigger it, but when I trigger the next sound. It shifts all sounds.

I've came up with the idea that it happens becouse the load method opens a clip that is then used by a different Sound instance, ¿Shoudn´t it just load it's clip?

Like I said, if a call the load method right after start, it freezes sometimes.
I've created a thread to run it, so that it doesn't  hang the main thread, but it freezes anyway so the sound plays late.

```
public class Sound {

    private final String file;
    private static Clip clip;

    public Sound(String file){
        this.file = file;
        load();
    }

    public final void load(){
        try {
            AudioInputStream stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(file).getAbsoluteFile());
            clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            System.out.println(clip);
            clip.open(stream);
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException | LineUnavailableException  ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Sound.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public void play() {
        clip.start();
        clip.addLineListener(e -> {
            if (e.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP) {
                clip.stop();
                clip.close();
                load();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

I expect the audio to played at the moment when it's triggered.

Comment: Are you playing the sounds more than once?  If so, you are invoking addLineListener more than once, which is going to cause strange behavior.  Try moving the addLineListener call into your `load` method, so it’s only called once per Clip object.

Comment: I've moved addLineListener to the constructor, so it doesn't get called more than once, since load is called everytime the clip is over.
But now no matter what sound I trigger, the sound it plays is always the same.

Comment: I just noticed that `clip` is a static field.  That means all Sound instances are using the same Clip object!  Make it a non-static field.

Comment: I cannot express how excited and ashamed I'm. Thank you so much, it works fine now.

Comment: Glad you fixed your problem, but code can be improved more.
If you are going to reload a sound file repeatedly, use SourceDataLine, not Clip. SourceDataLine will start playing immediately (as soon as a buffer's worth of data is loaded). Clip has to finish loading the entire sound file before it will play. Basically, if you ever have to reload a Clip, you are misusing it. It was specifically written to hold sound data in memory for reuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. It was such a stupid mistake. Clip was the same to all clases, not becouse getClip() returned the same value, but becouse I set it to be static.
Just changed:

```
private static Clip clip;
```

to

```
private Clip clip;
```

Comment: *"It was such a stupid mistake."* LOL. I've made three so far today, and still have time left for more. Smart move on solving the problem and plus one for reporting the solution.